# sqlalchemy doesn't recognize my mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-connector-python

Im trying to connect with SQLAlchemy to Mysql database on my localhost.
It throws in an error message saying that the database doesn't exist, which it does. I created it in the Workbench, and used it in other scripts.

My commands in the python shell

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqlconnector://username:password@127.0.0.1:3306/databaseName")
conn=engine.connect()
```

This is pretty much according to the documentation [here][1].

The complete error message:

```
ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1049 (42000): 
Unknown database 'databaseName'
```

Does anyone have any idea what it is that goes wrong?
Any help is appreciated!

**[1]: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.mysqlconnector

Answer (score 0):

well, I'd say, `databaseName` does not exist in your local MySQL database. Be aware, despite MySQL is not case sensitive at column names, etc., it is very sensitive when talking about database names. So make sure, that it's really `databaseName`, not `databasename` nor any other weird combination.

Btw, use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` in your connection string.

Regards, Thomas

Comment: I changed the localhost to 127.0.0.1:3306. The databasename is correct, I double checked that. So far, still nothing, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you use mysql from command line?
i.e. `mysql --host=localhost --user=username --password=password databaseName`

Comment: Another idea is to use pymysql instead of the mysql.connector.